# Could Jesus save Satan?

Tags: sin, soteriology, satan

Could Jesus save Satan?

Some biblical reference with explanation, would be helpful.

Comment: The better question is: Does Satan want to be saved?

Comment: As Satan was a fallen angel, the answer to this question also answers yours. [Can angels be saved?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2464)

Comment: @Lime - could you give us a frame of reference here? Are you looking for a specific doctrinal stance on this subject? Is there are particular church or denomination's stance you would prefer? Could you at least narrow it down to a denomination or set of denominations? Thanks. For now I've closed the question. Please edit it to provide some kind of framework.

Comment: Yes Jesus could save Satan and as someone who believes in Apokatastasis I believe that in one sense he already has, although this is still being worked out in history and will probably not come to completion until after the new creation. For biblical reference read the beginning of collosians where it talks about *all things* being saved and renewed in Christ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Bible reveals no provision of salvation for angelic beings, while it speaks quite a bit about the provision of salvation for mankind.  It also speaks of "the eternal fire" as a place prepared for the devil and his angels...

> Then he will say to those on his left, 'Depart from me, you cursed,
>   into the eternal fire prepared for the devil and his angels.  Matthew
>   25:41 ESV

Theologically speaking, there is no "first Adam" of the race of angels, because they neither marry nor are given in marriage.

> For in the resurrection they neither marry nor are given in marriage,
>   but are like angels in heaven.  Matthew 22:30

So, without a "first Adam", there could be no "Second Adam", and consequently, no Savior.

Answer (score 5):

There is very little in Scripture directly about Satan, so biblical references aren't really going to exist.

One thing to clarify, however, is the meaning of *Satan* as opposed to Beelezub, Lucifer, or the Devil.  It should be noted that while we all think this is the same bad guy, the primary reference to Satan (and really the only one from which much can be gleaned) is in the first two chapters of Job.*

Ha-Satan literally means "the Accuser."  To "save" a (false) accuser, presumably from the results of his lying would mean forcing him to withdraw his charge.  Once "the Accuser" is no longer Accusing, what is he?  He can be defeated (and will be!), or silenced, but to be "saved" would be to deny the very essence of what he is.

Thus, the answer is "No."

Its not because God doesn't have the power, or even the desire - its because of the law of non-contradiction.

*For completeness' sake, here are all the references, via Wikipedia:

> Ha-Satan with the definite article occurs 13 times in the Masoretic Text, in two books of the Hebrew Bible:
>
> Job ch.1–2 (10x)
> Zechariah 3:1–2 (3x)
>
> Satan without the definite article is used in 10 instances, of which two are translated diabolos in the Septuagint and "Satan" in the King James Version:
>
> 1 Chronicles 21:1, "Satan stood up against Israel" (KJV) or "And there standeth up an adversary against Israel" (Young's Literal Translation)[8]
> Psalm 109:6b "and let Satan stand at his right hand" (KJV)[9] or "let an accuser stand at his right hand." (ESV, etc.)